# When entering 0 in the inputbox the code doesn't execute

Tags: excel, vba

I made a form for multiplying, dividing, adding and subtracting multiple cells with an input value.

Everything works except if I put 0 to the inputbox then the code doesn't execute.

```
Private Sub cmdMultyply_Click()
Dim cell_value As Double
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim nmr As Variant
Dim formula As String

nmr = Application.InputBox("Insert a number.", "INPUT", Type:=1)

If nmr = False Then Exit Sub

Set rng = Selection

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell_value = cell.Value
        formula = Replace(cell.FormulaLocal, "=", "")
        cell.FormulaLocal = "=(" & formula & ")" & "*" & nmr
    End If
Next

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: `If nmr = False`.  When compiling, `0` is equal to `False.` Therefore you exit the sub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> If nmr = False Then Exit Sub
> ```

The `InputBox` returns a `Variant`. If that variant's subtype is `Boolean`, you know you don't need to handle it.

So validate the variant subtype:

```
If VarType(nmr) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub
```

And now both `"False"` and `0` are valid values.

Comment: It returns a variant even though I'm specifying the type:=1? OK, I see. So in case of nmr = 0 the VarType function returns vbDouble and the code executes. OK, I get it. 
Thanks @mathieu guindon

Answer (score 2):

It is because

```
0 = False
```

And it exits the sub

Change

> `If nmr = False Then Exit Sub`

To

```
If CStr(nmr) = "False" Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, works great for 0 now. But if I put a string in or cancel the inputbox it multyplies the cell.formula with "False".
What is actualy vbCancel doing?

Comment: @MrZH6 the type:=1 input box should not allow a text string, but you are correct on the cancel.  see edit.

Comment: @MrZH6 Sorry realized I pasted into the wrong place, see edit.

Comment: That's fine I got it @scott craner. Thank you very much.